# JSON parse valueerror - Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a valid JSON file and running into the following error. I have also validated my JSON structure.

**Error:**

```
  parseJSON = json.loads(jsonFilePath);
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**Code :**

```
vendorID = input('ENTER the vendor ID :');
jsonFilePath="C:/Users/user/Desktop/maradata.json";
parseJSON = json.loads(jsonFilePath);
```

I have also pasted JSON data here:
http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/23471909

Can anyone suggest me where I am running into error?

Comment: `json.loads()` takes a *JSON string*, not a filename. See the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

There are two method to **load** `string` to `json`:

1. `json.loads(s)`  `s` is string.
2. `json.load(fp)`  `fp` is file Pointer.